# Add custom styles to mat-select placeholder?

Tags: sass, angular-material, angular8

I'm using Angular 8, with scss type.

I want to change color in the placeholder of mat-select.

If I use class:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

It can works with any mat-select control.

But if I define a custom class like this:

```
::ng-deep .customclass .mat-form-field-label {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And the html:

```
            <mat-select matNativeControl placeholder="Student" class="customclass">
              <mat-option value="101" selected>Krishna</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="102">Mahesh</mat-option>
              <mat-option value="103">Shiva</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
          </mat-form-field>
```

It doesn't apply color anymore. How can I change css so that it can work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the label is rendered as a sibling of mat-select element, try the below CSS selector, this should change the color

```css
::ng-deep .mat-select.customclass + .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label {
  color: green !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thank Stash, it worked now. But I confuse about '+' in your script. What does it mean? What will happen if we just write: .mat-select.customclass .mat-form-field-label-wrapper .mat-form-field-label (without use '+')

Comment: '+' targets the sibling element with the class .mat-form-field-label-wrapper, if you remove it the browser will expect .mat-form-field-label-wrapper to be inside the .mat-select element, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your selector.

You’re using a descendent selector when you should be combining the classes.

Descendent:

```
::ng-deep .customclass .mat-form-field-label
```

Combined:

```
::ng-deep .customclass.mat-form-field-label
```

Comment: thank @Dan Mullin, but I changed to combine class, it didn't work too.